# Where do you load the Google Maps API in a GWT project?

Tags: google-maps, gwt

In my project.gwt.xml file I have

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?gwt=1&amp;file=api&amp;v=2&amp;sensor=false;key=MYKEY" />
```

But, when I load my page I get the google map gadget to come up, but with no map and an error message "Your page is missing the Google Maps API."  Is there a different place I need to load the API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like I got it to work myself.  I added to my project.html file:

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&v=2&key=MYKEY" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And it started working.  Probally not the best way of solving the problem, but it worked!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you use the [Google Maps Library for GWT](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/).  You'll have a much easier time than if you try to get the standard Google Maps API working in your GWT project.

Comment: I am, but Google's documentation is tarrible, out of date, and lacking meny details.  That is the reason I am asking SO for a better discription.